# Regexp, полное совпадение слова

Tags: регулярные-выражения, search, mysql

Проблема состоит в том что если написать такой код для поиска слова

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `text` REGEXP 't';
```

то будет находить все результаты t и все слова что начинаются на t ,
а нужно что бы искало точное совпадение с буквой t или же выводить результаты ревалентно.

То есть сначала все записи где только буква t присутствует в строке одна, как одно слова, а потом уже и все слова которые начинаются на t тоже попадают в результат поиска.

Конечно думаю проще сделать точное совпадения буквы t в строке, но если не на много сложнее написать ревалентный поиск то помогите правильно написать правильную строку запроса.

Comment: REGEXP '^t$';

Comment: @wwvv это не подойдет потому что это будет работать только если строка содержит t, а допустимо и text t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что это самый оптимальный вариант в плане производительности, но вот решение (**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25db8/11)**):

**Таблица:**

```
+--------------------+
|id |  text          |
|---+----------------|
|1  |  'Carrot'      |
|2  |  'Hello t'     |
|3  |  'All mighty t'|
|4  |  'Batman'      |
+---+----------------+
```

**Запрос:**

```
SELECT * FROM (
              SELECT * 
              FROM `table`
              WHERE `text` REGEXP '[[:<:]]t[[:>:]]' #только целое слово
              ORDER BY `text` ASC
              ) AS t
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
              SELECT *
              FROM `table`
              WHERE `text` REGEXP 't' #все варианты
              ORDER BY `text` ASC
              ) AS t1;
```

**Результат:**

```
+--------------------+
|id |  text          |
|---+----------------|
|3  |  'All mighty t'|
|2  |  'Hello t'     |
|4  |  'Batman'      |
|1  |  'Carrot'      |
+---+----------------+
```

Comment: Все хорошо, вот только можно сортировать первый запрос по id DESC , я конечно побывал и сам, но такое чувство что первый запрос вообще ничего не отдает.

проблема еще в том что я перед началом данных подставляю символ #, и нужно найти вот такие данные #t , в БД такие записи есть но первый запрос просто дает пустой ответ

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7a28/3 вот почему-то первый запрос дает 0 результатов

Comment: @M11, потому что слово может состоять только из **букв**, **цифр** и **нижнего знака подчеркивания**. Вынесите знак решетки за рамки слова.  
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7a28/10    
[Документация][1]
  [1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html